# Jquery AutoComplete Select Functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am developing a webpage in which I am using jquery autocomplete, the source of jquery autocomplete is an object literal of name and value. The name is showing in the autocomplete list. I want when the user click on the item of autocomplete, the page should be redirect to the link which I have store in the name field. How its possible?

Comment: what did you try, can you post the code ?

Comment: Are you using a select box or a text field. Please be clear

Comment: Dear I tried that I append the href with name of object literal but on the selection of item, it is not redirecting to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use onChange event for the textfield selector and in that use window location  href with name of object literal.

```
       $('#textField').onChange(function() {
       window.location.href="location you want to redirect";
      });
```

Tell if this help or i have to make an edit